# When I import an .obj file from a Euro Truck Sim 2 mod into Blender 2.83 the model has random geometry clipping through the truck

Tags: modeling, import, error

I've imported an .obj file of someone's custom Euro Truck Sim 2 model into Blender 2.83. However when I import the .obj file it's coming out looking odd with random chunks clipping trough the truck, along with a random plane beneath the truck.

Here is a link to the truck I'm trying to import : https://gamemodels.ru/files/file/5175-daf-xf-euro-6/

And below is an image of how the truck is coming out once imported.
[image]

Comment: Maybe different level of detail models on top of each other?

Comment: This theory makes sense to me. Do you have idea how I can alter between the different level of details as opposed to having them all enabled at once?